# How do I print characters to the console while inputting in x86 assembly with irvine

Tags: assembly, x86, console, masm

I am required to write a login function that takes username and password and checks it for validity. The problem is I want to display the ***** character on the console when the user enters the password instead of what user is typing. So if the password is 123, when user types, it only shows ******* characters on the console. How do I do that in x86 assembly?

```
LOGIN PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1  ; Asking for username
    call WriteString

    mov edx, OFFSET inputuser
    mov ecx, strsize
    call ReadString

    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, lengthof username

username_loop:
    mov eax, inputuser[esi]
    cmp al, username[esi]
    jne invalid_username

    inc esi
    loop username_loop

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2  ; Asking for password
    call WriteString

    mov edx, OFFSET inputpass
    mov ecx, strsize
    call readPassword

    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, lengthof password

password_loop:
    mov eax, inputpass[esi]
    cmp al, password[esi]
    jne invalid_password

    inc esi
    loop password_loop

    ; Successful login
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt5  ; Valid username and password. Logging in...
    call WriteString

;;;    This is not taking input and only printing a line of *************
invalid_username:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt3  ; Invalid username
    call WriteString
    jmp end_login

invalid_password:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt4  ; Invalid password
    call WriteString
    jmp end_login

end_login:
    call Crlf
    RET
LOGIN ENDP

readPassword PROC
    mov ebx, strsize
    mov esi, OFFSET inputpass

readPasswordLoop:
    mov eax, 0
    call ReadKey
    cmp al, 0AH  ; Check for Line Feed (Enter key on some systems)
    je  end_readPassword
    mov [esi], al
    mov eax, '*'  ; Display asterisk for each character
    call WriteChar
    inc esi
    dec ebx
    jnz readPasswordLoop

end_readPassword:
    mov byte ptr [esi], 0  ; Null-terminate the password string
    call Crlf
    RET
readPassword ENDP
```

This is not taking input, only printing a line of *********** and declaring invalid password.

Comment: You should use `ReadChar` instead of `ReadKey` as that does not wait for a keypress. Also note it might be returning `CR` first.